# How can i open an .png file with an .sh file?

Tags: scripts

Im using an .desktop file to launch an .sh file that launchs multiple programs.So i want to open a .png file with the .sh file, but i use some terminal commands and it dont show it. Here is an example of the .sh file im using:

```
!/bin/sh
start four terminal sessions in the background
gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal
gnome-terminal
/directory/pngfile.png
```

I also used:

```
mirage pngfile.png
```

Sorry for my bad english, im from South America

So, how can i open an .png file with an .sh file?

Comment: Use `xdg-open pngfile.png`.

Comment: I used your command

Comment: xdg-open pngfile.png

Comment: But it still dont showing the file, it stills dont launchs the image.

Comment: Do i have to mention the program that needs to use?

Comment: An example: [theimageviewer] /directory/pngfile.png or [imageviewer] pngfile.file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for my question is to use:

```
cd /directory/
eog pngfile.png
```

eog is a real image viewer.
One hour looking the answer myself.

This also works:

```
xdg-open pngfile.png
```

muru gave me this command.

Comment: Just for kicks, replace `eog` with `xdg-open` in the example you have given and tell me what happens.

Comment: Yes, it did work too, i was wasting time on looking the command for image viewer instead of using the command you gave me.

Comment: Wow.. this question was crap.